# AWS policy actions for querying a CloudWatch log group and extracting information from the results

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-policies

I am trying to query the AWS CloudWatch logs that are created by a Lambda Function. I have written a script to do this, which does the following:

1. `aws logs start-query`
   Submit a query, with the appropriate time window and query string.
2. `aws logs get-query-results`
   Return the log record pointer results from the query created in step (1).
3. `aws logs get-log-record`
   Dereference the log record pointers from step (2) to get the log stream IDs.
4. `aws logs get-log-events`
   Fetch the log events from the log streams found in step (3).

This works and now I'm trying to create a policy that will allow me to run all of the above without authentication. This is what I've come up with, going by the [AWS CloudWatch Logs permissions reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/permissions-reference-cwl.html):

```json
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
    "logs:GetLogEvents",
    "logs:StartQuery",
    "logs:DescribeQueries",
    "logs:GetQueryResults",
    "logs:GetLogRecord"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:logs:REGION:ACCOUNT:log-group:/aws/lambda/FUNCTION",
    "arn:aws:logs:REGION:ACCOUNT:log-group:/aws/lambda/FUNCTION:log-stream:*"
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes my script to fail at the second step. I can successfully create a query, but when I try to fetch its results, I get:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: User with accountId: ACCOUNT is not authorized to perform GetQueryResults

What am I missing? Clearly `GetQueryResults` is allowed, but it's still not working. What other actions do I need to allow for both step 2 and what follows to succeed?

Comment: Are you trying to access within same AWS account or cross account?

Comment: Same account. I found the problem with the help of the AWS policy warnings/suggestions. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `GetQueryResults` and `GetLogRecords` should not be limited to a particular CloudWatch resource and instead applied to everything. The following fixed the problem:

```json
[
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
      "logs:GetLogEvents",
      "logs:StartQuery"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:logs:REGION:ACCOUNT:log-group:/aws/lambda/FUNCTION",
      "arn:aws:logs:REGION:ACCOUNT:log-group:/aws/lambda/FUNCTION:log-stream:*"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "logs:GetQueryResults",
      "logs:GetLogRecord"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }
]
```